# MongoDB How to copy selected sample rows into another new collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to copy the output of the below MongoDB Aggregate query and make it a new collection :

```
  db.fd2000.aggregate([{
     $sample: {
         size: 333333
        }
    }], {
     allowDiskUse: true
  })
```

I am selecting a sample from the fd2000 collection and now want to copy this into a new collection say fd2ksample.

How do I do that?

A thousand thanks for your answers in advance !

Comment: In mongodb there is nothing as rows as such. Its called documents. Its NoSQL, not old SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator

```
db.fd2000.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 333333 }}, {$out: "fd2ksample"} ],{allowDiskUse: true})
```

Comment: It gives the below error                                                                                                            @felix    > db.fd2000.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 333333 }, {$out: "fd2ksample"} }],{allowDiskUse: true})
2017-02-07T12:39:30.473+0530 E QUERY    [main] SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell):1:50
>

Comment: @PuneetMathur my bad there was a bracket typo, it should work fine now

Comment: This does not create a new collection it just shows all the output on the screen  > db.fd2000.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 333333 } }],{allowDiskUse: true}, {$out: "fd2ksample"})

Comment: @PuneetMathur you're using the wrong syntax, teh $out stage goes in the aggregation pipeline, not in the options

Comment: I am accepting your answer as this one worked: > db.fd2000.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 333333 } }, {$out: "fd2ksample"}],{allowDiskUse: true})